# Python Pandas Drop Duplicates keep second to last

Tags: python, pandas

What's the most efficient way to select the second to last of each duplicated set in a pandas dataframe?

For instance I basically want to do this operation:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(['Person','Question'],take_last=True)
```

But this:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(['Person','Question'],take_second_last=True)
```

Abstracted question: how to choose which duplicate to keep if duplicate is neither the max nor the min?

Comment: What is the identifying column data like?

Comment: Abstracted question: If duplicates are actual duplicates, why would second to last matter, otherwise they are not duplicates.

Comment: @Merlin my understanding is that `[Person, Questions]` are the only columns pandas will consider when identifying the duplicates, so all of the remaining column may have distinguishing values.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With groupby.apply:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4], 
                   'B': np.arange(10), 'C': np.arange(10)})

df
Out: 
   A  B  C
0  1  0  0
1  1  1  1
2  1  2  2
3  1  3  3
4  2  4  4
5  2  5  5
6  2  6  6
7  3  7  7
8  3  8  8
9  4  9  9

(df.groupby('A', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x if len(x)==1 else x.iloc[[-2]])
   .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
Out: 
   A  B  C
2  1  2  2
5  2  5  5
7  3  7  7
9  4  9  9
```

With a different DataFrame, subset two columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4], 
                   'B': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4], 'C': np.arange(10)})

df
Out: 
   A  B  C
0  1  1  0
1  1  1  1
2  1  2  2
3  1  1  3
4  2  2  4
5  2  2  5
6  2  2  6
7  3  3  7
8  3  3  8
9  4  4  9

(df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x if len(x)==1 else x.iloc[[-2]])
   .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
Out: 
   A  B  C
1  1  1  1
2  1  2  2
5  2  2  5
7  3  3  7
9  4  4  9
```

Answer (score 5):

You could `groupby/tail(2)` to take the last 2 items, then `groupby/head(1)` to take the first item from the tail:

```
df.groupby(['A','B']).tail(2).groupby(['A','B']).head(1)
```

If there is only one item in the group, `tail(2)` returns just the one item.

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10**2, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
result = df.groupby(['A','B']).tail(2).groupby(['A','B']).head(1)

expected = (df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x if len(x)==1 else x.iloc[[-2]]).reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
assert expected.sort_index().equals(result)
```

The builtin groupby methods (such as `tail` and `head`) are often much faster
than `groupby/apply` with custom Python functions. This is especially true if there are a lot of groups:

```
In [96]: %timeit df.groupby(['A','B']).tail(2).groupby(['A','B']).head(1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.7 ms per loop

In [97]: %timeit (df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x if len(x)==1 else x.iloc[[-2]]).reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
100 loops, best of 3: 17.9 ms per loop
```

---

Alternatively, [ayhan suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957036/python-pandas-drop-duplicates-keep-second-to-last/38965036?noredirect=1#comment65284901_38965036) a nice improvement:

```
alt = df.groupby(['A','B']).tail(2).drop_duplicates(['A','B'])
assert expected.sort_index().equals(alt)

In [99]: %timeit df.groupby(['A','B']).tail(2).drop_duplicates(['A','B'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.43 ms per loop
```

Comment: `.drop_duplicates(['A', 'B'])` instead of `.groupby(['A','B']).head(1)` seems slightly faster.

Comment: @ayhan: Thanks for the improvement!