# pandas dataframe groupby and return nth row unless nth row doesn't exist

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like so:

```
    date        id          person                      latitude    longitude
0   2016-07-11  1           rob                         41.395279   2.162126
1   2016-07-11  1           harry                       51.485146   0.041339
2   2016-07-11  1           susan                       51.496457   0.051234 
3   2016-07-11  2           lenny                       48.863281   2.339698
4   2016-07-11  2           wendy                       51.522469   -0.148812
5   2016-07-11  3           john                        51.490746   -0.022011
```

I want to group this dataframe by both date and ID, then return the second row of this group for the other three columns. In the case that there is only one row for that group, then I want it to return the first row (i.e. not drop the group).

Currently I have the following but this is dropping occasions where there is only one instance of that group.

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['date', 'id']).nth(1).reset_index()
```

The output I am aiming for is:

```
    date        id          person                      latitude    longitude
0   2016-07-11  1           harry                       51.485146   0.041339
1   2016-07-11  2           wendy                       51.522469   -0.148812
2   2016-07-11  3           john                        51.490746   -0.022011
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use `apply` and pick up the row according to the number of rows for each group:

```
df.groupby(['date', 'id']).apply(lambda g: g.iloc[1,:] if g.shape[0] >= 2 else g.iloc[0,:]).reset_index(drop = True)

#         date  id  person   latitude  longitude
#0  2016-07-11   1   harry  51.485146   0.041339
#1  2016-07-11   2   wendy  51.522469  -0.148812
#2  2016-07-11   3    john  51.490746  -0.022011
```

Comment: I like this solution, but @Psidom, I have this question (4 yrs later the answer was given): what if in the ```else``` case, the row should contain NaN?

Answer (score 4):

Similar to unutbu's approach to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38957036/2285236), you can take the first two (if you have one, head(2) will return only 1) and drop the duplicates keeping the last (2nd) occurrence:

```
df.groupby(['date', 'id']).head(2).drop_duplicates(['date', 'id'], keep='last')
Out: 
        date  id person   latitude  longitude
1 2016-07-11   1  harry  51.485146   0.041339
4 2016-07-11   2  wendy  51.522469  -0.148812
5 2016-07-11   3   john  51.490746  -0.022011
```